# Linear regression outputs "inf" value

Tags: python, linear-regression

I'm trying to learn linear regression, gave this problem a try. The results of the adjusted b(bias) and m(linear coefficient) are being outputted as "inf" or "-inf", what should i do?

sorry if the problem in the code is obvius, I'm new at this.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import random

x = [1,2,3,3,4,4,3,2,1,2,5,4]
y = [1,2,2,1,3,4,1,1,2,3,4,5]
b = random.random()
m = random.random()
learning_rate = 0.3
iterations = 1000

for i in range(iterations):
    for k in range(len(x)):
        X = m * x[k] + b
        
        derivative_error = 2 * (X - y[k])
        
        dX_dm = x[k]
        dX_db = 1
        
        m += derivative_error * dX_dm * learning_rate
        b += derivative_error * learning_rate
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I get it right, you are trying to use gradient descent to solve the linear regression
model. Here are the problems with your approch:

**First:**
The derivative is incorrect, instead of of

```
X = m * x[k] + b
        
derivative_error = 2 * (X - y[k])
        
dX_dm = x[k]
dX_db = 1
        
m += derivative_error * dX_dm * learning_rate
b += derivative_error * learning_rate
```

it should be taking the derivate of the error with respect to `m` and `b`.

**Second:**
You don't update the gradient every time you see a data point `x[k]`, like what you are doing in the inner for-loop of your code:

```
for k in range(len(x)):
        X = m * x[k] + b
        
        derivative_error = 2 * (X - y[k])
        
        dX_dm = x[k]
        dX_db = 1
        
        m += derivative_error * dX_dm * learning_rate
        b += derivative_error * learning_rate
```

Instead, you accumulate errors of all `x` and average them. Use the averaged error to update ypur `m` and `n`.

**Third:**
Perhaps your `learning_rate` set to `0.3` is too large, such that it 'overshoots' the optimimum point at each of your update and hence the value of `m` and `b` get to a very wild number all the way to `inf`.

That said, the following is my solution, with a `error` function to check the
average errors you get at every iteration.

```
def error(x,y, m, b):
    error = 0
    for k in range(len(x)):
        error  = error + ((x[k] * m + b - y[k]) **2)
    
    return error

from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import random

x = [1,2,3,3,4,4,3,2,1,2,5,4]
y = [1,2,2,1,3,4,1,1,2,3,4,5]
b = random.random()
m = random.random()
learning_rate = 0.01
iterations = 100

for i in range(iterations):
    print(error(x, y, m, b))
    d_m = 0
    d_b = 0
    for k in range(len(x)):

        # Calulate the derivative w.r.t. m and accumulate the error
        derivative_error_m = -2*(y[k] - m*x[k] - b)*x[k]
        d_m = d_m + derivative_error_m
        
        # Calulate the derivative w.r.t. b and accumulate the error
        derirative_error_b = -2*(y[k] - m*x[k] - b)
        d_b = d_b + derirative_error_b
    
    # Average the derivate of errors.
    d_m = d_m / len(x)
    d_b = d_b / len(x)
    
    # Update parameters to the negative direction of gradient.
    m = m - d_m * learning_rate
    b = b - d_b * learning_rate
```

After running the code for `iterations = 10`, you get:

```
15.443121587504484
14.019097680461613
13.123926121402514
12.561191094860135
12.207425702911078
11.985018705759003
11.8451837105445
11.757253610772613
11.70195107555181
11.66715838203049
```

where errors are shrinking at every update.

**Besides, you should also notice that a simple model like linear regression. There is a nice closed-form solution which gets you the opitimum solution immediately without applying iterations such as gradient descent.**